What's the critical path for this IIR filter? Is my analysis correct?
The following is a pair of retimed IIR filter.

The top:
$$T_{cp} = T_{mult} + T_{add}$$
The bottom:
$$T_{cp} = max(2T_{add}, T_{mult})$$
Is my analysis correct?

Can we assume that $X(n)$ also comes from a "T" register? What about clock-to-output and input setup times for a "T" register?

@DaveTweed "T" is time delay element

Yes, a register with a clock. That's the whole point of this exercise.

@DaveTweed Is my analysis correct? I don't think you have to consider the  time for "T" in critical path according to the book.  (https://www.amazon.com/Integrated-Circuits-Academic-Press-Engineering/dp/0127345302)

@DaveTweed "T" is depicted as $Z^{-1}$ in some textbooks
